# How to save to a file the Fluent nHibernate 1.1 HBM XML configuration?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am having a issue with it as described here:
[Fluent NHibernate 1.1: when multiple column name mappings are used on different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998541/fluent-nhibernate-1-1-bug-when-multiple-column-name-mappings-are-used-on-differen)

As someone pointed, I need to see the HBM XML configuration to help to debug.

I have a config FluentConfiguration config object working:

```
config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

How to save to a file the Fluent nHibernate 1.1 HBM XML configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way:

```
config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.ExportTo(@"C:\temp\mappings"));
```